# Problem with ASP.NET 2.0 GridView hidden Columns are shown on Postback

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2005

Please Help,
I have User Control that contain GridView where i am hiding its Columns on GridView RowCreated event :

```
    private void gvGrid_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

                foreach (TableCell objCell in e.Row.Cells)
                {
                   if (objCell is DataControlFieldHeaderCell)
                    {
                            objCell.Visible = false;
                    }
                }

    }
```

Now every thing was working fine, but On ASPX Page Postback ( containing Griview UserControl), shows all hidden columns, where my PageLoad is as follows

```
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
               if (!IsPostBack)
               {
               ucGridView.PopulatePage();
               }
          }
```

Note : ASPX Page start working fine if i remove !IsPostBack Check..but i dont want this...Whats the Problem...!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the RowDataBound event handler instead of RowCreated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to make the columns invisible in the code-behind?

If you just need to store field values in the grid but not display them then [Microsoft recommends using the DataKeyNames property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx) of the GridView control.

Instead of using code-behind to hide certain columns, you can just remove the bound fields from the GridView and specify them in the DataKeyNames property:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        DataKeyNames="SalesOrderID,SalesOrderDetailID"
        DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
```

This way the fields will not show to the user but the GridView knows to keep the values around for updating, etc.

Answer (score 1):

By Default your column visible in the grid and you are hiding when page is not postback

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
  {
        ucGridView.PopulatePage();
  }
```

so

```
technically ucGridView.PopulatePage(); is only beign called once thats why when you remove 
!IsPostBack is works fine.
```

Answer (score 0):

if used in RowDataBound then u cant access griview Column value